# Why is importing a module from a sibling package considered an anti-pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just started learning how to code in Python (came from a Java background).

I have this very basic project structure, using the simplest form of MVC I can muster:

```
myproject
    controllers
        __init__.py
        controller.py
    models
        __init__.py
        model.py
    views
        __init__.py
        view.py
    main.py
```

Provided that I start with view.py and I need to make a link between this and its controller, I know that I have to import the controller by using the import commands:

`from controllers import controller`

I know for a fact that this doesn't work, so I use relative paths in order to try and make it work.

`from ..controllers import controller`

I also know that this doesn't work as it can't really see the folder, in order to fix that I need to make the myproject folder a package in and of itself. But this doesn't make sense to me.

I read somwehere that this kind of file structure is an "anti-pattern" almost. But why though? MVC is structurally sound by decoupling their functions, so separating them into their own packages makes sense.

Comment: You first of all must start to think in terms of packages and modules, *not files!* Your project is a package. It's one of the packages available in your Python installation, no different from any other installed package. You then have the choice to do absolute imports like you'd do from any other package (`from myproject.controllers ...`), or do relative imports within your package, which is mostly just shorthand and perhaps guards a bit against renaming stuff. What about this makes no sense to you?

Comment: @deceze In his case `myproject` is not a package (missing `__init__.py`). Also `main.py` seems to be the entry point which would add `myproject` to the `PYTHONPATH` by default. With that `from controllers import controller` should work fine.

Comment: @Klaus OP acknowledges that they should make `myproject` a package. And they should. It doesn't make a lot of sense to have a global module "`controllers`", it should clearly belong to a package.

Comment: @deceze in that case `main.py` seems to be little misplaced assuming it will be used to run the project.

Comment: So wait, it's alright to make your entire project a package in and of itself?

Comment: It's not only alright, it's what you should do. Always think in terms of publishing your project to PyPI or building a wheel from it to install on your production server (even if you're never going to do either of those things).

Comment: @deceze Is this how frameworks like Django do it? I don't want to emulate a vanilla MVC framework to run with only to realize that it's not how it's usually done.

Comment: When using Django, you're actually creating several packages within your project ("apps") which you're then bundling together into one "project". Both "apps" and "projects" are installable modules in their own right, yes.

Comment: Also, I keep reading about other questions being asked, most of them usually do the hacky method by modifying the path using the sys import. I would reasonably conclude that since they're doing that, they're not making the root a package. Is that right? And if it's not why are others not doing it like the way that I'm doing it?

Comment: Right, whenever you're hacking your Python path because you can't locate your module, it's a sign that you're not thinking about your project in the right way and haven't set it up appropriately in its environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not think in terms of "files", but in terms of *packages*. Your entire project should be its own package which is installed in your Python environment like any other package. There's no fundamental difference between these:

```
from django.db import models

from myproject.controllers import controller
```

`django` is a globally installed package. `myproject` should be a globally installed package.

If wouldn't make sense to have a global "`controllers`" module floating around, it should clearly be part of a larger package.

Within a package you can do relative imports if you want to, which is mostly shorthand and perhaps helps a bit if you rename the top level package, but is otherwise inconsequential.

Always think in terms of eventually publishing your package to PyPI or building a wheel which you distribute to production servers for installation, even if you're never going to do either of those things.